# Hibernate: Setting a primitve type from join

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and am stumped by something that seems incredibly simple!

I have a table defining a Contact and a view that gives the contact an approved status.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contacts")
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = BooleanType.class)
    @JoinTable(
            name="contactstatus",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="email")
    )
    private boolean approved; 

    ...
}
```

I simply want to set the approved flag by joining the view on the email primary key.

Running the above gives me:

```
Initial SessionFactory Creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
    @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ...Contact.approved references an unknown entity:
            org.hibernate.type.BooleanType
```

I realise I could combine the contact and approval columns into a single view, however other aspects of the contact are mutable.

I could also make Approved a custom type, and this is actually how I am working around this issue. However, I don't think this should be necessary in order to make the above work.

Comment: A target entity, by definition, must be an entity. boolean is not an entity. Tell us what the tables look like and how they're related with each other.

Comment: Well I guess that answers my question in that I need to use the "Approved" type mentioned to encapsulate the email <> approved. Thanks